# acute-angled triangle

Tags: geometry, triangles, angle

I try to solve this problem:
I have an acute triangle $ABC$ and its heights intersect at point $S.$ I drew the situation. I have to find the length of $AS$. I know that $\angle BAC=45^{\circ}$ and $|BC|=7.$ Have you got any ideas?

Thanks for your help!

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$AP=PC$, $SP=PB$ and $\angle SPA=\angle BPC=90^{\circ}$ and thereafter $\triangle APS \cong \triangle CPB$. Thus $AS=BC=7$.

Comment: Please read [Enforcement of Quality Standards](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/33508/enforcement-of-quality-standards?cb=1), on math.meta.  This question will likely be closed, until improved.

Comment: Doesn't a diagram count as sufficient context? The rules are not so clear-cut here, and I've seen questions much worse than this one.

Comment: @Toby Mak I answered it considering that.